# Rails 4: Database Entry is empty and exists

Tags: postgresql, post, ruby-on-rails-4, commit

First, the Problem:

```
Started POST "/weapons" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-07-06 00:13:15 +0200
Processing by WeaponsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Token-Raus-editiert", "art"=>"Schwert", "name"=>"Excalibur", "angriff"=>{"{:in=>1..6, :step=>1}"=>"5"}, "block"=>{"{:in=>1..6, :step=>1}"=>"2"}, "zustand"=>{"{:in=>1..100, :step=>1}"=>"100"}, "button"=>""}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Weapon Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "weapons"  WHERE "weapons"."name" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Weapon Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "weapons"  WHERE "weapons"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/weapons/new
Completed 302 Found in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 1.6ms)
```

he tells me, the weapon i try to create, already exists. What is correct, in his logic. Because, he tries to commit "Nothing" but the ID and the creation_date. So, i have just an empty field in my Database.

This, is the Form which sends the request:

```
<%= form_for @weapon  do %>
    <div class="WeaponGenerate">
      <table>
        <th><h1>Eine neue Waffe erschaffen</h1></th>
        <tr>
          <td>Welche Sorte Waffe soll es sein?</td>
          <td><%= select_tag :art, options_for_select(['Schwert', 'Axt', 'Bogen']) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Der Name für die Waffe soll sein?</td>
          <td><%= text_field_tag :name %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Angriffswert</td>
          <td><%= number_field(:angriff,  in: 1..6, step: 1) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Blockwert</td>
          <td><%= number_field(:block,  in: 1..6, step: 1) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Zustand?</td>
          <td><%= number_field(:zustand,  in: 1..100, step: 1) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><%= button_tag('Waffe erschaffen') %></td>
      </table>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

and this the Controller:

```
class WeaponsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @weapon = Weapon.all
  end

  def new
    @weapon = Weapon.new
  end    

  def create
    @weapon = Weapon.new(weapon_params)
    if @weapon.save
      flash[:notice] = "Schwert erschaffen!"
      redirect_to(:action => 'show')
    else
      flash[:error] = "Leider gab es ein Problem!"
      redirect_to(:action => 'new')
    end
  end

  private
  def weapon_params
    params.require(:weapon).permit(:art, :name, :angriff, :block, :zustand) if params[:weapon]
  end
end
```

and at least, the model, with annotations:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: weapons
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  art        :string(255)
#  name       :string(255)
#  angriff    :integer
#  block      :integer
#  zustand    :float
#  kick       :hstore
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime
#

class Weapon < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :bySword, lambda { where(:art => 'Schwert' ) }
  scope :byAxe, lambda { where(:art => 'Axt') }
  scope :byBow, lambda { where(:art => 'Bogen') }
  scope :sorted, lambda { order("weapons.art ASC") }
  scope :newest_first, lambda { order("weapons.created_at DESC")}
  scope :search, lambda {|query|
    where(["name LIKE ?", "%#{query}%"])}

    validates_presence_of :art, :name, :angriff, :block, :zustand
    validates_uniqueness_of :name, :id
end
```

Do someone see my mistake? I dont. So i hope you can help me.

Comment: What happens if you remove `if params[:weapon]` in `weapon_params`?

Comment: That brings me to an interesting error ive never seen before:

SystemStackError in WeaponsController#create 
stack level too deep